# Laravel VPS installation problem - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: php, laravel, vps

I'm installing Laravel using composer and when trying to run any php artisan command I get this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in /var/www/html/portal/bootstrap/app.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/portal/artisan(20): require_once()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/portal/bootstrap/app.php on line 14
```

Basically I'm using [this guide](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-laravel-7-on-ubuntu-20-04-with-nginx-and-mariadb) and I'm getting stuck at step 2.5 `php artisan serve...`

I'm unable to figure whats wrong but I suspect it is something with this path found in **app.php**

```
$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    $_ENV['APP_BASE_PATH'] ?? dirname(__DIR__)
);
```

I'm trying to install it on Vultr VPS. Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: its a new project or existant ?

Comment: its a new project (its actually my beginners learning platform)

Comment: try to use laravel requirement checker to check all version and php ext are compatible and installed

Comment: and if the problem only on serve try to rename serve.php to index.php and try to access to it by url

Comment: seems like i was missing DEV keys